# ReplaceOne Method's Filter Matches Document, Does Not Perform Replacement

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm experiencing some strange behavior using the C# driver for MongoDB.  I'm attempting to perform an update that replaces multiple fields, so I'm using the `ReplaceOneAsync()` method from the API.  My connections to any collection is made with `WriteConcern.Acknowledged` so I can handle cases where the database fails to be updated for whatever reason (like in this situation).

Sometimes the database will not update a record, but I cannot determine *why*.  When attempting to debug this case I am looking at the `ReplaceOneResult` object returned from the ReplaceOneAsync method and it shows that MatchedCount = 1, but the ModifiedCount = 0 as seen in the screenshot below from my debugger:

[image: Debugging Screenshot]

How is this possible?  If it matched the one id that I'm trying to replace, why wouldn't it perform the modification?  Does this mean there is some sort of error state occurring causing it to fail silently?  It doesn't throw any exceptions so if this is the case how can I determine what's going wrong?

Here's the simple update method:

```
public virtual async Task<bool> Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity.Id == ObjectId.Empty)
        throw new ArgumentException("Id must be available and in the database to perform an update.");

    ReplaceOneResult result = await this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id, entity);
    return result.ModifiedCount > 0;
}
```

Comment: I am getting modified count but still its not replaced. Still no one has answer. Have you find any solution?

Comment: @KalpeshChheda I never figured out a solution to this or determined what was going on behind the scenes.  The application I was working on where I experienced this actually stopped using mongodb altogether so I never bothered to continue researching this issue once it was depreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the MatchedCount = 1 and ModifiedCount = 0 it should be because your replacement document is identical to the existing document.

So they matched, but no replacement was necessary because they were identical.